# ddslick select options won'st post value of selected option - jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using ddslick to make drop down menu's with icons, the only trouble is when I post the form the value of the selected option is always empty, it works fine if I turn ddslick off.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.cflagdd').ddslick({
 onSelected: function(selectedData){
    //callback function: do something with selectedData;
   // $('#editcflag').submit(); - this does not work, posts form on page load
}   
});
</script>

<select class="cflagdd" name="cflag">
<option value="0" selected="selected">No action flag set</option>
<option value="1" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-green-icon.png">Resolved</option>
<option value="2" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-yellow-icon.png">Investigate</option>
<option value="3" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-red-icon.png">Urgent</option>
<option value="4" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-blue-icon.png">False positive</option>
</select>
```

Versions:
Jquery-1.7.2.js
jQuery UI - v1.8.20

Thanks for any help, much apreceated

Answer (score 13):

There's a bug in ddslick that leaves the hidden inputs without a name attribute.

I was able to add a couple lines to ddslick to get it to add the select's name attribute to the hidden element it creates.

First, download the uncompressed version of ddslick: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40036711/Scripts/jquery.ddslick.js

Then add the following on line 106, or right after the lines starting with "var ddSelect = ..." :

```
// set hidden input name
ddSelect.find('input.dd-selected-value').attr('name', $(this).attr('name'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a better solution than this one but what I did when I ran into this is I took my selected value and placed it into a hidden input element.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.cflagdd').ddslick({  
        onSelected: function(selectedData){  
            if(data.selectedIndex > 0) {
                $('#hidCflag').val(data.selectedData.value);

                $('#editcflag').submit();
            }   
        }    
    }); 
</script>  

<input type="hidden" name="hidCflag" id="hidCflag" value="" />

<select class="cflagdd" name="cflag"> 
    <option value="0" selected="selected">No action flag set</option> 
    <option value="1" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-green-icon.png">Resolved</option> 
    <option value="2" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-yellow-icon.png">Investigate</option> 
    <option value="3" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-red-icon.png">Urgent</option> 
    <option value="4" data-imagesrc="'.base_url().'images/Actions-flag-blue-icon.png">False positive</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Snipe656 conceptual idea works but the script has a mistake. The correct script part should be:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.cflagdd').ddslick({  
        onSelected: function(data){  
            if(data.selectedIndex > 0) {
                $('#hidCflag').val(data.selectedData.value);

                $('#editcflag').submit();
            }   
        }    
    }); 
</script>
```

(...)

Answer (score 3):

```
Solution
<select id="status" name="status" class="ddslick" >
        <option  value="1">Admin Only</option>
        <option  value="2">Editing</option>
        <option value="3">Review</option>
        <option  value="4">Live</option>
</select>

<script>
$("select.ddslick").each(function(){
        var name =  $(this).attr('name');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#"+id).ddslick({
            showSelectedHTML: false,
            onSelected: function(selectedData){
                $("#"+id+ " .dd-selected-value").prop ('name', name);
             }  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it by dynamically adding a name to the hidden input that stores the value of the selected option.

In the HTML:

```
<select id='locationList'> 
  <option value="a">a</option>
  ...
</select>
```

In the Javascript:

1. "ddslick" it:

   ```
   $('#locationList').ddslick();
   ```
2. Dynamically add name attribute to hidden

   ```
   $('#locationList').find('input[type=hidden]:first').attr("name", "location");
   ```

Answer (score 2):

FInd this text in **jquery.ddslick.min.js**
and add a name to this

```
<input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" />
```

This will be sending correct data to server

```
<input class="dd-selected-value" name="cflag" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Download Stable Version

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jsmodules/ddslick/master/src/jquery.ddslick.js

I have tried almost any of the answers given. Some did not work for multiple instances, while others have broken links to fixed  scripts. I have found this up to date version of ddSlick which actually fixed this 'bug'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix for this:

https://github.com/ahmeij/ddslick/commit/6a085996428dd6f1a06a6fd2195c8f4f13d8ab28

FIND THIS LINE IN THE UNMINIFIED SOURCE CODE (AROUND LINE 103)

```
 obj.addClass('dd-container').append(ddSelectHtml).append(ddOptionsHtml);
```

AND ADD THIS BELOW IT:

```
// Inherit name attribute from original element
obj.find("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", $(original).attr("name"))
```

**This fixed the issue for me!**

Answer (score 0):

The ddslick plugin changes all select-tags, and creates a new hidden `<input>`-field for them. Look into your code and you'll probably find an undefined input:

```
<input name="undefined" id="undefined" class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="1">
```

Something that is not all to clear on the [plugin-page](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) is that the plugin needs a surrounding div AND a name and id for the select-tag to work properly. So use:

```
<div id="cflagdd_container">
    <select class="cflagdd" name="cflag" id="cflag">
          <option value="0">No action</option>
          <option value="1" selected data-imagesrc="...">Resolved</option>
          ...
     </select>
</div>
```

Now you have a valid input:

```
<input name="cflag" id="cflag" class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="1">
```

Refer to the container in your jquery:

```
$('.cflagdd_container').ddslick();
```

Comment: I did what you said and my input has never a name + id just the class="dd-selected-value" and I have to create an extra hiddenfield to get the selected value to the webserver on form submit.

Comment: Does your original tag have an id?

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to put the *selectedData* of *ddslick* in a field like *input.hidden*. Then, *ddslick* renders an *input* element into HTML. No way a html-element sends data when you do a simple form-submit. ;)

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your answer to make it more readable. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: @Spontifixus You are welcome to edit such answers yourself. Not only you'll improve the quality. You'll even get some extra reputation.

Comment: @KonradViltersten JavaScript is not my core area of expertise, so I am not sure what is to be formatted as code and what simply is emphasized. Additionally edits only changing the formatting tend to get rejected as too minor. Usually I do the edit myself, but in this case I decided that the author of the question (or someone with more expertise on that topic) could do a better job than me.

Comment: @Spontifixus I don't agree with the "change too minor" argument. The size of a change and its significance are two different things. However, I understand your point. I edited the post a little bit (not huge guru of JS neither).

Answer (score 0):

@John J

I had the same problem like you. All these tips/hints here did not help.

The problem with ddslick its buggy. There is no name sent with the selected item but this

should be.

Try this successor:

http://ddslickremablized.remabledesigns.com/

Your bug is fixed in this version. The selected item will be sent correctly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me.

```
$('.cflagdd').ddslick({
 onSelected: function(selectedData){
    $('.dd-selected-value').prop ('name', 'cflag');
}   
});
```