# Get value of selected <option> in ddSlick dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

This currently returns undefined. What should go in the commented line to alert the value (1, 2, 3 or 4) of the current `<option>` tag?

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="images/icons/all.png">All Questions</option>
        <option value="1" id="friends" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends.png">Friends</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends_of_friends.png">Friends of Friends</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="images/icons/network.png"><?php echo $network; ?></option>
        <option value="4" data-imagesrc="images/icons/location.png"><?php echo $location ?></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dropdown').ddslick({
showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
    var str = $(this).attr('id'); // WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?
    alert(str);
    }   
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If it's relevant, I'm using [this plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick).

Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453578/ddslick-select-options-wonst-post-value-of-selected-option-jquery-plugin) might help. I'm trying to make sense of it.

Managed to figure this out. Final working code is:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" value="hello">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="images/icons/all.png">All Questions</option>
        <option value="1" id="friends" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends.png">Friends</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends_of_friends.png">Friends of Friends</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="images/icons/network.png"><?php echo $network; ?></option>
        <option value="4" data-imagesrc="images/icons/location.png"><?php echo $location ?></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dropdown').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(data){
        alert(data.selectedData.value);
    }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to get value of selected option when you select it?

Comment: Yes, so the choices are 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: What's in `selectedData`? Isn't that the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for your plugin, the `onSelected` method gets the `selectedData` parameter:

> selectedData (nested object with text, value, description, imageSrc)

The text label and value are available as `selectedData.text` and `selectedData.value` inside the `onSelected` function. Try this:

```
$('#dropdown').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        var str = selectedData.value
        alert(str);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was basically it. See my edit for final working code.

Comment: it gives me alert undefine 

here is code 

`$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
      onSelected: function(selectedData){
          var str = selectedData.value
          alert(str);
      }   
  });`

Answer (score 5):

Use `$(this).val()` in place of `$(this).attr('id')`

The value of the currently selected `<option>` is returned when you call `.val()` on the `<select>` element.

Comment: Please see my comment below. Adding this freezes the dropdown.

Comment: None relevant to this. They all concern other plugins.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#dropdown').ddslick({
showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
    var str = $(this).val()
    alert(str);
    }   
});
```

So, use `val()` instead of `attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

> I got it!! if you want to get the attribute value you set in your array where your data is coming from you get your value like this->

```
$('#id').ddslick({
    data:dropdowndata,
    width:60,
    selectText: "Select Circle",
    imagePosition:"left",
    //dropdowndata[4].selected:true
    onSelected: function(selectedData){ 
    val = selectedData.selectedIndex;
    alert(dropdowndata[val].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post the data, create a hidden input, use jquery to set the value of the hidden field then post the hidden field

`$('.ddslick_drop_down').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
      //set the value to a hidden field then post the hidden field
      $('#dish_id').val(selectedData.selectedData.value);`

Answer (score -2):

> I got the selected index from ddslick and assinged a value to seperate input >fields.this way I can have input fields to control my form. I've been coding >for 3months now so i don't really know what i'm doing. This is a long way of >doing it but it seems to work so...

```
onSelected: function(selectedData){
    alert("selectedData.selectedIndex");
    if(selectedData.selectedIndex == 1 ){
        $("#input1").html(selectedData.selectedIndex);
    }
    if(selectedData.selectedIndex == 2 ){
        $("#input2").html(selectedData.selectedIndex);
    }
    if(selectedData.selectedIndex == 3 ){
        $("#input3").html(selectedData.selectedIndex);
    }
}
```