# How to get value of selected in ddSlick dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use some ddslick drop down menus in a form and I want to get the selected values when submit that form.

Already try to create a hidden input near that menus:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput"  />
```

then I assign the selected value to that input name:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

                //Dropdown Básico
                for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
                $('#dropdownBasico'+i).ddslick({
                    data: ddData,
                    width: 150,
                    imagePosition: "left",
                    selectText: "some texts",
                    onSelected: function(data){
                     if(data.selectedIndex > 0) {
                              $('#hiddeninput').val=selectedData.value;
                            alert(selectedData.value);
                        }  
                    }
                }); 
}
```

But the value I get is always empty. Please advice the solution, and note that I have several menus here (thats why I use for loop to change the name accordingly). I already research some similar questions like: [Get value of selected <option> in ddSlick dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995178/get-value-of-selected-option-in-ddslick-dropdown) and [ddslick select options won'st post value of selected option - jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453578/ddslick-select-options-wonst-post-value-of-selected-option-jquery-plugin) and tried them but get no working solution ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the value in wrong way

```
 $('#hiddeninput').val=selectedData.value;
                //---^^^^^ here
```

in jquery, it should be

```
  $('#hiddeninput').val(selectedData.value);
```

`.val()` to get the value of specified selector..
`.val('test')` to set

> note that I have several menus here (thats why I use for loop to change the name accordingly)

if such is the case then use same class for all menus and use class selector

```
 $('.dropdownBasicoClass').ddslick({
     ....
```

Comment: Actually I tried what you suggested in the first place but it also give blank result, thats why I changed to the 'wrong' one. I just tried again what you mentioned, and still not get the value.

Comment: are you getting this value alert(selectedData.value); in alert ??

Comment: No, because when I submit the form, it will call another php file (this file I print all POST to a file to see ). So I think the alert will disappear

Comment: Ok, I disable the submit to see alert, and I get "undefined" in alert; code: var ddData = $('#dropdownBasico'+i).data('ddslick');alert(ddData);

Comment: If I alert(ddData) (for a single case without the loop, to eliminate complexity) then I get: [object Obeject]. But displaySelectedData("2: Getting Selected Dropdown Data", ddData); cannot display, look like it is a wrong format. In either way, I cannot get the value, do you have any idea ? Pls help !

Comment: `if such is the case then use same class for all menus and use class selector`can you explain this a little bit more ? I don't use that method, still can get drop down menu but I think there is some problem when I get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, source http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Dropdown Básico
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('#dropdownBasico'+i).ddslick({
        data: ddData,
        width: 150,
        imagePosition: "left",
        selectText: "some texts",
        onSelected: function(data){
         if(data.selectedIndex > 0) {

                alert('Selected value: '+data.selectedIndex);
                alert('Selected text: '+data.selectedData.text);
                alert('Selected description: '+data.selectedData.description);
                
            }  
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: not sure what is that displaySelectedData do, but I tried, no result. Also tried: var ddData = $('#dropdownBasico'+i).data('ddslick');
       displaySelectedData("Selected Dropdown Data" , ddData);
       $('#hiddeninput').val(ddData); same blank value

Comment: check here, http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo  No.3 - GET Selected Dropdown Option,   replace it with alert(); and try again.

Comment: as I commented below, tried and that wont return any value. I used this ddslick in my code : https://github.com/devluis/ddslick

Comment: ok, it s the same one, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/cYH6r/ , go to No.3, and select from select box and click the button "Get Selection", you can see the selected values.

Comment: So you mean: $('#hiddeninput').val(ddData); should return some data in POST ?

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/cYH6r/1/ , go to Demo No.3, select any one and click "Get Selection"button, to see selected value, text and description. Check script line no.60

Comment: I tried to put this into a function:       document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = 'ddData'; and call that function when click submit. I can do that for simple example already, but cannot assign ddData, because the function need to be in head

Comment: ddData is an object that has all index, value, text and description. Can you see the alert boxes that show your select item's value, text,etc....??

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get to hiddeninput? if you want 'text',
just use $('#hiddeninput').val(data.selectedData.text);

Comment: I want to get the value only. But now I event dont get anything from all that index, value, text and description. I tried alert(val(data.selectedData.text)); it shows nothing.

Comment: I tried again your link at :jsfiddle.net/yeyene/cYH6r/1 ; the update is so cool ! So I actually can get that value to $('#hiddeninput'); however when print out the POST value, its value is blank, look like the POST cannot capture it. There is no problem with POST method, other values I POST are ok.

Comment: I think I was going very close! Now I can get the value and the POST precisely. But it only for a single drop down. If I have several drop down, I need to use a loop:`for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#dropdownBasico'+i).ddslick({    
     data: ddData,` then how should I declare data ? I try normal declaration, it can not work. Because `ddData = $('#dropdownBasico'+i).data('ddslick');alert(ddData.selectedIndex)` will give error! It doesn't show error message so I dont know what it is, but alert() after that will not appear. Please give me your idea !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //Dropdown Básico
      for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
      $('#dropdownBasico'+i).ddslick({
          data: ddData,
          width: 150,
          imagePosition: "left",
          selectText: "some texts",
          onSelected: function(data){
             alert(data.selectedData.value);
          }
      }); 
}
```

Comment: instead of using function(selectedData.){
             alert(selectedData.value);
          }   use  function(data){
             alert(data.selectedData.value);
          }